# Prove that if $T[V]=\ker(T)$, then $n$ is even, where $\dim(V)=n$

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove that if $T[V]=\ker(T)$, then $n$ is even, where $\dim(V)=n$

We know that from the dimension thereom:

**rank(T) + nullity(T) = n**

So we can say that $n=\dim(T[V])+\dim(\ker(T))$

But I don;t know how to go on from here. What exactly does it mean when it says: $T[V]=\ker(T)$

I am aware there is a similar question to this already on MSE, but the answer didn't provide details and so I'm finding it hard to understand:

[Let $V$ be $n$ dimensional real vector space. Show that of $T[V]=\ker(T)$, then $n$ is even](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/531649/let-v-be-n-dimensional-real-vector-space-show-that-of-tv-kert-then)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image is the same as the kernel so in particular the rank and nullity of $T$ are equal.

Comment: but why does this imply $n$ even

Comment: @KSplitX: $x + x = 2x$

Comment: In that way, okay thank you

Answer (score 1):

Combine your $n=\dim(T[V])+\dim(\ker(T))$ and $T[V]=\ker(T)$ to get $$n=\dim(T[V])+\dim(T[V])=2\dim(T(V))$$

so $n$ is even.